# POST request using Rest Assured with Headers and Request Body

Tags: java, testng, rest-assured, cucumber-java

I am trying to setup code in such as way that executes a POST request in my step definition class, and the POST request includes authorization (bearer token), content type, and Cookies in headers, as well as a request body in json format.

I have the bearer token process setup and am using the bearerToken for the authorization as header, content type is application/json, and the request body has the below structure:

[image: Req Body]

I am unsure how to proceed in this way using Rest Assured.  Below is a given method that sets the base uri and the bearer token based on environment, and based on that the bearer token will be used accordingly for authorization as header when executing the POST request:

```
@Given("Request the environment for the Master API {string}")
    public void getMasterAPIBaseUrl(String region) throws JSONException {
        if (region.equalsIgnoreCase("DEV")) {
            bearerToken = accTokenSetup.accessTokenSetup(region);
            RestAssured.baseURI = urlProps.getProperty("devMasterAPIUrl");
        }
        else if (region.equalsIgnoreCase("STG")) {
            bearerToken = accTokenSetup.accessTokenSetup(region);
            RestAssured.baseURI = urlProps.getProperty("stgMasterAPIUrl");
        }
        Reporter.log("Getting master api base url for the environment which is " + RestAssured.baseURI, true);
    }
```

Now I need an @When step that will execute the mentioned POST request with the request body and the headers (authorization, content-type, and Cookies).  I know what is required would be the endpoint, headers, request body, etc. but unsure of how to proceed with it.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Ideally, your business logic shouldn't be there in Step Definition files, instead use the same in Utils/ Helpers/ Parsers java files and thereafter, create a Rest Client using the request body, method and base URI to make the corresponding network calls.

Comment: Not clear what the issue is. Are you asking about how to specify authorization token for your post request?